# Is the embedding of $W^{2,p}$ onto $C^1(\overline{I})$ compact?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

We know that when $I$ is a bounded interval and $1<p\leq \infty$ that the injection $W^{1,p}\subset C(\overline{I})$ is compact.

The proof of this fact uses the Arzela-Ascoli theorem on the unit ball $\mathcal{H}$ of $W^{1,p}(I)$. Is it true that the embedding of $W^{2,p}$ onto $C^1(\overline{I})$ is also compact?

**Please Comment on This Part**

Suppose that $u\in W^{2,p}$ then $u'\in W^{1,p}$ and thus $u'\in C(\overline{I})$
and therefore $u\in C^1(\overline{I})$.

Now let $\mathcal{H}$ be the unit
ball in $W^{2,p}$. Then $\mathcal{H}$ is equicontinuous since for all 
$u\in \mathcal{H}$,
$$|u(x)-u(y)|=\left|\int_{y}^xu'(t)dt\right|\leq \|u'\|_p|x-y|^{1/p'}\leq 
|x-y|^{1/p'}.$$
Hence by Ascoli-Arzela, $\mathcal{H}$ has compact closure in $C(\overline{I})$.
Since $\mathcal{H}\subset C^1(\overline{I})\subset C(\overline{I})$ then 
$\mathcal{H}$ has compact closure in $C^1(I).$ Is there anything wrong with the argument?

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with this argument. Why should the fact that a set has compact closure in $C(\overline{I})$ imply that it has compact closure in $C^1(\overline{I})$? (For instance, the unit ball of $C^1(\overline{I})$ has compact closure in $C(\overline{I})$, but certainly not in $C^1(\overline{I})$.)

Comment: However, you can characterize compactness of subsets of $C^1(\overline{I})$ by using that $C^1(\overline{I}) \ni f \mapsto (f', f(0)) \in C(\overline{I}) \times \mathbb{R}$ is an isomorphism of Banach spaces. Then it is not difficult to see that $W^{2,p}(I)$ embeds indeed compactly into $C^1(\overline{I})$.

Comment: Though I like the idea of $f\mapsto(f',f(0))$, I don't think the map as defined is bijective unless we take equivalence classes of functions up to a constant and then take $C^1(\overline{I})/\sim $.

Comment: The bijectivity follows immediately from the fundamental theorem of calculus. You don't need to factor out the constants since the map distinguishes them by the component $f(0)$ in its image.